# custom PHP in MODX with a snippet

Tags: php, code-snippets, modx

Ok, so I made a calculator in PHP and am trying to port i it into MODX via a snippet. I tried just putting all this code into the snippet and it doesn't work. It keeps giving me an error message and I can't view the resource that the snippet is on. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

```
<?php
function selected( $val = "")
{
$units = isset( $_POST['units'] ) ? $_POST['units'] : null;
echo ( $units == $val ) ? "CHECKED='CHECKED'" : "";
}
$units = isset( $_POST['units'] ) ? $_POST['units'] : null;
$dia = isset( $_POST['dia'] ) ? $_POST['dia'] : null;
$depth = isset( $_POST['depth'] ) ? $_POST['depth'] : null;
$L = isset( $_POST['L'] ) ? $_POST['L'] : null;
$num = isset($_POST['num']) ? $_POST['num'] : null;
$waste = isset($_POST['waste']) ? $_POST['waste'] : null;
$knownvolume = isset($_POST['knownvolume']) ? $_POST['knownvolume'] : null;
$hw = isset($_POST['hw']) ? $_POST['hw'] : null;
//$denom = ( ( $units == "US" ) ? 12 : 100 );
$tubecoverage = ( ( $units == "US" ) ? 18.59 : 304.65);
$onegalcoverage = ( ( $units == "US" ) ? 231 : 3785.41);
$twogalcoverage = ( ( $units == "US" ) ? 462 : 7470.82);
$fivegalcoverage = ( ( $units == "US" ) ? 1155 : 18927.06);

$measurements = 'in or cm';
    if( $units == 'US' ){
    $measurements = 'in';
}
    if($units == 'Metric')
{
    $measurements = 'cm';
}

if($units == 'US')
    $length = 'feet';
    else if($units == 'Metric')
    $length = 'meters';
    else 
    $length = 'feet or meters';

$tubes = ($tubes);
    if($knownvolume == TRUE)
    $tubes = (($knownvolume / $tubecoverage) * ($waste + 1) * 1.05);
    else 
    $tubes = (((($dia / 2) * ($dia / 2) * pi()) / $tubecoverage) * ($waste + 1) * 1.05);

$onegal = ($tubes);
    if($knownvolume == TRUE)
    $onegal = (($knownvolume / $onegalcoverage) * ($waste + 1) * 1.05);
    else 
    $onegal = (((($dia / 2) * ($dia / 2) * pi()) / $onegalcoverage) * ($waste + 1) *     1.05);

$twogal = ($tubes);
    if($knownvolume == TRUE)
    $twogal = (($knownvolume / $twogalcoverage) * ($waste + 1) * 1.05);
    else 
    $twogal = (((($dia / 2) * ($dia / 2) * pi()) / $twogalcoverage) * ($waste + 1) * 1.05);

$fivegal = ($tubes);
    if($knownvolume == TRUE)
    $fivegal = (($knownvolume / $fivegalcoverage) * ($waste + 1) * 1.05);
    else 
$fivegal = (((($dia / 2) * ($dia / 2) * pi()) / $fivegalcoverage) * ($waste + 1) * 1.05);

?>
<form method='post' action=''>
<table border='0' width='500px' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='1' class="calculator">
<tr class="calcheading"><td><label><input type="radio" name="units" 
<?php  selected("US")?> value="US" />S.A.E.</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="units" <?php selected("Metric")?> value="Metric"   />Metric</label> </td></tr>

<tr class="calcheading"><td colspan="2"><strong>Cicular Volume Area</strong></td></tr>

<tr class="calcrow"><td>Known Volume (<?php echo $measurements ?>):</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='knownvolume' value="<?php echo $knownvolume ?>"/>     </td></tr>

<tr class="calcrow2"><td>Dia (<?php echo $measurements ?>):</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='dia' value="<?php echo $dia ?>"/></td></tr>

<tr class="calcrow"><td>Length (<?php echo $measurements ?>):</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='L' value="<?php echo $L ?>"/></td></tr>

<tr class="calcrow"><td>Waste Variance % (Please add in decimal form):</td><td     align="center"><input type='text' name='waste' value="<?php echo $waste ?>"/></td></tr>

<tr class="submit"><td colspan="2"><input type='submit' value='Calculate'/></td></tr>

<tr class="calcrow">
<td><i>10.3 oz Tube(s) (CS-1500):</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($tubes, 2)?>"/></td></i>
</tr>
<tr class="calcrow">
<td><i>1 Gallon Bucket(s) (CS-1000):</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($onegal, 2)?>"/></td></i>
</tr>
<tr class="calcrow">
<td><i>2 Gallon Bucket(s) (CS-1800):</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($twogal, 2)?>"/></td></i>
</tr>
<tr class="calcrow">
<td><i>5 Gallon Bucket(s) (CS-1000/CS-1500):</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($fivegal, 2)?>"/></td></i>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: It works properly when I test it outside of MODX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work like you expect.

Snippets in Modx are pure php, so you can't use multiple `<?php` and `?>`'s to separate the code. In addition, because of the way snippets are cached, you have to wrap every function within a `if (!function_exists('nameoffunction')`.

Here I have rewritten some of the code. The idea is that all the info that you need in the html is put in an array. I've called this `$parse_arr`. At the bottom of the script, I use Modx's method to replace all the placeholders from the chunk with values from the array.

```
<?php
$parse_arr = array();


if (!function_exists('selected')) {
    function selected( $val = "") {
        $units = isset( $_POST['units'] ) ? $_POST['units'] : null;
        return ( $units == $val ) ? "CHECKED='CHECKED'" : "";
    }
}

$units = isset( $_POST['units'] ) ? $_POST['units'] : null;
$dia = isset( $_POST['dia'] ) ? $_POST['dia'] : null;
$depth = isset( $_POST['depth'] ) ? $_POST['depth'] : null;
$L = isset( $_POST['L'] ) ? $_POST['L'] : null;
$num = isset($_POST['num']) ? $_POST['num'] : null;
$waste = isset($_POST['waste']) ? $_POST['waste'] : null;
$knownvolume = isset($_POST['knownvolume']) ? $_POST['knownvolume'] : null;
$hw = isset($_POST['hw']) ? $_POST['hw'] : null;
//$denom = ( ( $units == "US" ) ? 12 : 100 );
$tubecoverage = ( ( $units == "US" ) ? 18.59 : 304.65);
$onegalcoverage = ( ( $units == "US" ) ? 231 : 3785.41);
$twogalcoverage = ( ( $units == "US" ) ? 462 : 7470.82);
$fivegalcoverage = ( ( $units == "US" ) ? 1155 : 18927.06);

$measurements = 'in or cm';
    if( $units == 'US' ){
    $measurements = 'in';
}
    if($units == 'Metric')
{
    $measurements = 'cm';
}

if($units == 'US')
    $length = 'feet';
    else if($units == 'Metric')
    $length = 'meters';
    else 
    $length = 'feet or meters';

$tubes = ($tubes);
    if($knownvolume == TRUE)
    $tubes = (($knownvolume / $tubecoverage) * ($waste + 1) * 1.05);
    else 
    $tubes = (((($dia / 2) * ($dia / 2) * pi()) / $tubecoverage) * ($waste + 1) * 1.05);

$onegal = ($tubes);
    if($knownvolume == TRUE)
    $onegal = (($knownvolume / $onegalcoverage) * ($waste + 1) * 1.05);
    else 
    $onegal = (((($dia / 2) * ($dia / 2) * pi()) / $onegalcoverage) * ($waste + 1) *     1.05);

$twogal = ($tubes);
    if($knownvolume == TRUE)
    $twogal = (($knownvolume / $twogalcoverage) * ($waste + 1) * 1.05);
    else 
    $twogal = (((($dia / 2) * ($dia / 2) * pi()) / $twogalcoverage) * ($waste + 1) * 1.05);

$fivegal = ($tubes);
    if($knownvolume == TRUE)
    $fivegal = (($knownvolume / $fivegalcoverage) * ($waste + 1) * 1.05);
    else 
$fivegal = (((($dia / 2) * ($dia / 2) * pi()) / $fivegalcoverage) * ($waste + 1) * 1.05);


$parse_arr['selected_us'] = selected("US");
$parse_arr['selected_metric'] = selected("Metric");
$parse_arr['measurements'] = $measurements;

$parse_arr['knownvolume'] = $knownvolume;
$parse_arr['dia'] = $dia;

// And so on

return $modx->getChunk('name-of-chunk', $parse_arr, '[[+', ']]');
```

Here's a part of the html. Save it as a chunk. The name must be the same as the chunk-name at the bottom of the snippet. (In this case I've called it name-of-chunk in my example).

```
<form method='post' action=''>
<table border='0' width='500px' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='1' class="calculator">
<tr class="calcheading"><td><label><input type="radio" name="units" [[+selected_us]] value="US" />S.A.E.</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="units" [[+selected_metric]] value="Metric"   />Metric</label> </td></tr>

<tr class="calcheading"><td colspan="2"><strong>Cicular Volume Area</strong></td></tr>

<tr class="calcrow"><td>Known Volume [[+measurements]]</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='knownvolume' value="[[+knownvolume]]"/>     </td></tr>

<tr class="calcrow2"><td>Dia [[+measurements]]</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='dia' value="[[+dia]]"/></td></tr>
```

You get the idea. Instead of having `<?php echo SOMETHING; ?>`, you use a placeholder `[[+name-that-correspond-with-parse-arr-key]]`.

You also have to write a snippet for the rounding-functions you are calling near the bottom of this chunk.

Have fun.

Comment: oh thank you, I appreciate it, you got me in the right direction

Comment: I assume the the return $parse_arr will look something like '[['+dia','+knownvolume','+depth']]'   correct?

Comment: Hey just an fyi i figured out how to round all my numbers up without creating an extra snippet. I just wrapped the whole equation with the ceil() call. My client wanted any decimal rounded to the next whole number so no biggie.

Answer (score 0):

Many years later and it still helped

```
if(!function_exists('process_the_files')) {
  function process_the_files() {
```

and

```
global $modx;
```

need to be in there